# line of code not working inside bash shell script

Tags: linux, grep

I have a line of code which is like this:

```
grep -f <(awk '{ print $1 }' fileA.txt | sed 's/\(.*\),/\1 /' ) fileB.txt > fileC.txt
```

It is working when I run it on the terminal but when I add it inside a *.sh script it gives this error:

```
format_input.sh: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

I tried to escape the () like this:

```
grep -f <\(awk '{ print $1 }' fileA.txt | sed 's/\(.*\),/\1 /' \) fileB.txt > fileC.txt
```

however, I still get some sort of error:

```
format_input.sh: line 12: (awk: No such file or directory
sed: ): No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you ran it through `shellcheck`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the correct answer, but I want to include more code than fits a comment. My guess is that you use a non-Bash shell to launch `format_input.sh`. I tested this with a simpler line. The file `file` contains this:

```
$ cat file
content
more content
this is a line
another one
```

Here is my test from the command line:

```
$ grep ON <(tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'< file)
CONTENT
MORE CONTENT
ANOTHER ONE
```

I put this line in a script that I name `script` and launch it like that:

```
$ bash script
CONTENT
MORE CONTENT
ANOTHER ONE

$ sh script
script: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
script: line 1: `grep ON <(tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'< file)'
```

(This is on Cygwin, but I don't think the particular platform matters)

Comment: This looks like a good hypothesis. Insure that the first line of your script is `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: my first line is #!/bin/bash I included it

Comment: shellcheck says there is no error

Comment: @PaoloLorenzini are you perhaps running the script using `sh format_input.sh`? That would override any shebang

Comment: oh yes, how to run it then?

Comment: oh just by bash format_input.sh ?

Comment: @PaoloLorenzini make it executable (`chmod +x format_input.sh`) then execute it by path only (i.e. `./format_input.sh` if it is located in the current directory); or place it somewhere in your `PATH` and then call it from anywhere as `format_input.sh`

Comment: `bash format_input.sh` works, and so does steeldriver's suggestion.

Comment: after I made it executable and I run with ./format_input.sh I got -bash: ./format_input.sh: Permission denied error but in any case, executing by bash format_input.sh worked, I was executing with sh which as we discussed was overriding the shebang, I understand

Comment: sorry, I think executing by  ./format_input.sh it is also working, all good, thanks